# CSS encapsulation for bootstrap modal pop ups

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have bootstrap.min.css messing up a lot of css in a web page I am working on. The bootstrap is only there for modal pop ups. I want to know if there is a way to ensure only the bootstrap.min.css is scoped/encapsulated for the pop ups?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the  Bootstrap customize section: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ , and select only the modal option in the components section.

Then Download the file, open the bootstrap.css file and copy the entire contents into your own CSS file, or just attach this file to your HTML doc.

Comment: It still requires me to keep the components for drop downs and other form css. So I'm not sure this is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Have you toggled all components before downloading (except what parts you need )? No requirements for that : http://screencast.com/t/p8N77e9QHc

Comment: Let me try again, there multiple elements in the modal which require a lot more than just selecting modal. What I want, is a way to encapsulate css only for this modal.

Answer (score 0):

you can customize bootstrap to just affect the modals in your website here is the link http://getbootstrap.com/customize/